# How to remove a list of words from a text ONLY IF it is a whole word, not a part of a word

Tags: python, text, replace

I have a list of word that I want to remove from a given text. With my limited python knowledge, I tried to replace those list of words with null value in a loop. It worked ok but the problem is it replaced all string matched to it even chunk of a word. Please look the code and output below:

```
word_list = {'the', 'mind', 'pen'}
def remove_w(text):
  for word in word_list:
    text = text.replace(word, '')
  return text
remove_w('A pencil is over a thermometer with mind itself.')
```

The output is:

> 'A cil is over a rmometer with  itself.'

It removed part of some words. However, clearly I wanted the following output below.

> A pencil is over a thermometer with itself.

How to remove such list of words from a text ONLY IF it is a whole word, not a part of a word. (Since I will use it on large articles, please suggest a way that is faster approach) Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression with word boundaries.

```py
pattern = re.compile('|'.join(rf'\b{re.escape(w)}\b' for w in word_list))
def remove_w(text):
    return pattern.sub('', text)
```

Alternatively, use `str.split` to separate into words delimited by spaces, remove the words exactly matching one of those in the `set`, then join it back together.

```py
def remove_w(text):
    return ' '.join(w for w in text.split() if w not in word_list)
```

Comment: I checked your first answer and it worked fine. "A pencil is over a thermometer with  itself.", Thanks a lot. But, as you can see, it keeps additional whitespaces where it removes a complete word. For example, here it has 2 whitespaces in between the words 'with' and 'itself' after removing word 'mind'. Is there any way like strip() method, to remove additional whitespaces between words? Thanks again

Comment: @RahatAhmed You can change the regular expression to also remove all whitespace following a matching word: `pattern = re.compile('\\b(' + '|'.join(re.escape(w) for w in word_list) + ')\\b\\s*')`

Comment: Hi Unmitigated(sorry couldn't find your name), I was trying your second answer for another reason, just like the first one, it was not designed to remove words that are with punctuations. For example, it can remove 'mind' but cannot remove 'mind,' or 'mind.' etc with punctuations. Would you please help to remove exact words but also with punctuations? Thank you.

Comment: Code Tried::: 
word_list = {'the', 'mind', 'pen','itself'} 
def remove_w(text):
    return ' '.join(w for w in text.split() if w not in word_list)
remove_w('A pencil and a pen, is over a thermometer with mind itself.')

Comment: @RahatAhmed To handle punctuation, you can modify the regular expression approach, but you need to explicitly list out all the punctuation you need.

Comment: Please help assuming punctuations are only comma, colon, and period. [',',':','.']

Comment: @RahatAhmed So do the punctuation also need to be removed?

Comment: No, For  word_list = {'the', 'mind', 'pen','itself'} , current output = "A pencil and a pen, is over a thermometer with itself.", BUT expected output "A pencil and a, is over a thermometer with."

Comment: using your second approach def remove_w(text):
    return ' '.join(w for w in text.split() if w not in word_list)

Comment: using your second approach def remove_w(text):
    return ' '.join(w for w in text.split() if w not in word_list)

Comment: @RahatAhmed Okay, this should handle it: `pattern = re.compile(r'\s*\b(' + '|'.join(re.escape(w) for w in word_list) + r')\b')`

Comment: If you have further problems, it is recommended to ask a new question.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. I actually asked the solution in your second approach, I am facing difficulties in the first approach with my data. Would you please solve the punctuation issue using your second approach (split and join one def remove_w(text): return ' '.join(w for w in text.split() if w not in word_list) )

Comment: With more complicated data, it'd probably be better to use regular expressions. Simple splitting and joining isn't going to work well. I can't tell what the exact issue with using my first approach is without any sample data.

Comment: Thank you for your help. In your first approach, when I tried non-english data, specifically(Bangla), I saw some in some words, it is still removing chunk of a word. For example, here is the code:::
import re
word_list={'এখানে', 'বললেন', 'না', 'নিজের'} 
pattern = re.compile('\\b(' + '|'.join(re.escape(w) for w in word_list) + ')\\b\\s*')
def remove_w(text):
    return pattern.sub("", text)
remove_w('আজ ৬২ বাংলাদেশির সে নাম রয়েছে বললেন।')

Comment: Here I can get the following output:"আজ ৬২ বাংলাদেশির সে ম রয়েছে ।" where it removes a matched chunk "না" with inputted word "নাম" and removed partially leaving "ম".  Expected output is "আজ ৬২ বাংলাদেশির সে নাম রয়েছে।"

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to remove whole words from the text while taking care not to remove parts of other words. In your specific case, you can use the `re` module to achieve that:

```py
import re

word_list = {"the", "mind", "pen"}
word_pattern = r"(\s?)\b(?:" + "|".join(re.escape(word) for word in word_list) + r")\b"
pattern = re.compile(word_pattern)

def remove_w(text):
    return pattern.sub("", text)

text = "A pencil is over a thermometer with mind itself."
result = remove_w(text)
print(result)
```

The output will be:

```
A pencil is over a thermometer with itself.
```

Explanation:

1. `re.escape(word)`: Escapes any characters that might have a special meaning in regular expressions, like `.`, `?`, `*`, etc.
2. `(\s?)`: Matches any whitespace and `?` to make it optional.
3. `'|'.join(...)`: Joins the words together with the regex OR pattern `|`.
4. `\b`: Matches the empty string but only at the beginning or end of a word.
5. `pattern.sub('', text)`: Replaces the matched words in the text with an empty string.

This approach should work efficiently even for large articles, as the regular expression engine is optimized for text processing tasks like these.